# How to use Navigation Keys as Input in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to use navigation keys to get input command from user. For Example:- When the user presses `Right` navigation key, a method should be called to perform some task. Below is the piece of code i tried to use for this purpose:

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    KeyPreview = true;
    this.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.MainForm_KeyPress);
}

private void MainForm_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyChar)
    {
        case (char)Keys.Right:
            NextMenuItem_Click(sender, EventArgs.Empty);
            break;
    }
}
```

Note that this worked fine for other keys like Alphabets, Numeric-Keys and Even enter key. But somehow not working for Left, Right, Up, Down navigation keys.

Please guide me. I shall be glad and thankful to you :-) 
Your Response will be appreciated ! 
 (I am using **Visual Studio 2017**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use that instead of your switch and handle the KeyDown event instead of the KeyPress event:

```
switch (e.KeyCode)
{
    case Keys.Right:
        NextMenuItem_Click(sender, EventArgs.Empty);
        e.Handled = true;
        e.Suppressed = true;
        break;
}
```

And I don't think that you need to set the `KeyPreview` option.
The problem with your code is that you try to parse the Right key to a char, which doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Okay Thanks Sir @MetaColon  ... Got the Point :-) 
I realize my mistake now !

Answer (score 1):

You may only access other keys next to the letters and numbers when handling the `KeyDown` event instead of `KeyPressed`.
Then you may utilize the `Keys` enum.

```
private void Mainform_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.Right:
            e.Handled = true;
            e.Suppressed = true;
            NextMenuItem_Click(sender, EventArgs.Empty);
            break;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please, note @MetaColon handling and suppressing the Keypress. However, don't forget to switch your event type.

Comment: Thank you, I've overseen that.